# Extending React.Component warnings

Tags: reactjs, typescript

When I extend React.Component like this:

```
export default class App extends React.Component<any, any > {

    constructor (props: React.ReactPropTypes) {
        super(props);
    }

// other code
}
```

I got the following warnings:

> ./src/App.tsx [37, 50]: Type declaration of 'any' loses type-safety.
>   Consider replacing it with a more precise type, the empty type ('{}'),
>   or suppress this occurrence. [37, 55]: Type declaration of 'any' loses
>   type-safety. Consider replacing it with a more precise type, the empty
>   type ('{}'), or suppress this occurrence.

Which is the best way to solve these warnings?

Comment: Try using `{}` instead, if your component doesn't really need anything from its props and state. If the component does demand something from its props/state, express that in the type signature.

Answer (score 1):

in yout tslint.json you can put:

```
{"rules": {
"no-any": false
 }      
}
```